# Setting class attributes of the proper type

Tags: python, class, variables

What is the most pythonic way to say what kind of info should be set as attributes of my class?

For instance, I have a class named `Human`, and the class's attributes accept specific data inside the variables.

- The hair must be black, blonde or bold,
- The age must not be above 110,
- The legs and hands have to be integers.
- The name has to be a string, etc.

What is the best way to achieve that?

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,name,legs,hands,age):
        self.name = name #must be a string
        self.legs = legs #must not be more than 2
        self.hands = hands #same goes as legs above
        self.age = age #must not be above 110
        self.hair = hair #must be among hair_list =  ['black','blonde','bold']
```

Comment: `if` statements for each attribute..

Comment: About half the time, type-checking/validation is anti-pattern. There's a reason that Python is dynamically typed. Are you sure you actually need to type-check?

Comment: fyi... the [oldest recorded age record is 122](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldest_people#Ten_verified_oldest_women_ever).

Comment: I agree. Just documenting your concerns should be enough for most use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle managed attributes is to use [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). Example:

```
class Name(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._name

    def __set__(self, instance, name):
        if not isinstance(name, basestring):
            raise ValueError('Name must be a string')
        self._name = name


class Human(object):
    name = Name()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Demo:

```
>>> h = Human(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.name = name
  File "test.py", line 7, in __set__
    raise ValueError('Name must be a string')
ValueError: Name must be a string
>>> h = Human('test')
>>> h.name
'test'
```

Also see: [Introduction to Python descriptors](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-pythondescriptors/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a better way than to be explicit about your intentions, although perhaps you could trust that anyone creating a `Human`-object would understand that you cannot be 500 years old.

I believe the most pythonic way is to `raise` a meaningful exception whenever one of the attributes do not validate. I'd also use default parameters so that you don't have to type the most common use cases all over again..

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, legs=2, hands=2, age=0, hair='blonde'):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise TypeError("Name must be a string")
        self.name = name 

        if legs > 2:
            raise ValueError("More than 2 legs")
        self.legs = legs 

        if hands > 2:
            raise ValueError("More than 2 hands")
        self.hands = hands 

        if age > 110:
            raise ValueError("What, are you immortal?!")
        self.age = age 

        if hair not in ['black', 'blonde', 'bold']:
            raise ValueError("I'm sorry your hair color is not cool enough")
        self.hair = hair
```

Examples:

```
In [15]: Human(123)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9998e6013647> in <module>()
----> 1 Human(123)

<ipython-input-13-65da6758e98d> in __init__(self, name, legs, hands, age, hair)
      2     def __init__(self, name, legs=2, hands=2, age=0, hair='blonde'):
      3         if not isinstance(name, str):
----> 4             raise TypeError("Name must be a string")
      5         self.name = name
      6 

TypeError: Name must be a string
```

Another one..

```
In [16]: Human("John", age=1500)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-09f5670add7c> in <module>()
----> 1 Human("John", age=1500)

<ipython-input-13-65da6758e98d> in __init__(self, name, legs, hands, age, hair)
     17 
     18         if age > 110:
---> 19             raise ValueError("What, are you immortal?!")
     20         self.age = age
     21 

ValueError: What, are you immortal?!
```